# Como otimizar este código?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, desempenho, expressões-lambda

Existe alguma forma mais rápida (performática) de comparar o valor atual com o valor anterior (do banco) com **Entity Framework**? Ao invés de selecionar `Id` por `Id` (conforme propriedade `Discount` do código abaixo), verificar o `array` inteiro, ou algo do tipo?

Com o código abaixo, verifico o ultimo preço do valor e calculo o desconto, porém, é feito `Id` por `Id`.

```
ha.AddRange(
    array.Select(
        x => new ProductHistory {
            ProductId = x.Id
                , Price = x.Price
                , LastUpdate = DateTime.Now.Date
                , Discount = x.Price / (
                    (Convert.ToDecimal(db.ProductHistory.Where((ProductHistory p) => x.Id == p.ProductId)
                        .OrderByDescending(o => o.LastUpdate)
                        .Select(y => y.Price)
                        .FirstOrDefault()) == 0) ? x.Price :
                    (Convert.ToDecimal(db.ProductHistory.Where((ProductHistory p) => x.Id == p.ProductId)
                        .OrderByDescending(o => o.Id)
                        .Select(y => y.Price)
                        .FirstOrDefault()))) * 100 - 100
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: Só pra eu entender: o que é `ha` e o que é `array`?

Comment: ha = ProductHistory[]
array = Product[]

Comment: Coloquei como array pois o AddOrUpdate do Entity só aceita array, se não seria uma lista.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isto que você está fazendo é péssimo em desempenho. Minha sugestão é:

```
// Selecione todos os Products envolvidos no que você quer.
// Adiante ProductHistory. Include() usa INNER JOIN.
var allProducts = db.Products
                    .Include(p => p.ProductHistory)
                    .Where(...).ToList();

// Aqui uso apenas operações em memória. 
// O jeito que você estava fazendo abria vários SQL em sequência, 
// o que não vale a pena pra operação que você está fazendo.
foreach (var element in array)
{
    var product = allProducts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == element.ProductId);
    var lastUpdateHistory = product.ProductHistory.OrderBy(ph => ph.LastUpdate).FirstOrDefault();
    var lastId = product.ProductHistory.OrderByDescending(ph => ph.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    element.Discount = lastUpdateHistory.Price > 0 ? array.Price : lastId.Price * 100 - 100;
}
```